# How to make sure only conditions that are true will print

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have data stored in firebase db for users.

*Filter Status* is a select tag with values: Completed, Pending, Scheduled. 
*Filter Month* is a select tag with all months listed.

```
dbRef.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
  removeOldRows()
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    let startDate = new Date(doc.data().startDate * 1000)
    let forMonth = ((startDate.getMonth() + 1))

    if (filterStatus.value === doc.data().status && parseInt(
        filterMonth.value) === forMonth) {
      let showData = `
                <tr class='tableDataRows'>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().name }</span></td>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().status }</span></td>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().type }</span></td>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().price }</span></td>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().userEmail }</span></td>
                </tr>
            `
      tableRow.innerHTML += showData

    } else {
      tableRow.innerHTML = 'No records found.'
    }

  })
})
```

**Desired Output -**

1. Upon selecting Status and Month db should fetch and show data accordingly;
2. If no data is found tableRow.innerHTML should display : *No Records found*.

**Example -**

Upon selecting Status as 'Pending' and month 'October' , tableRow.innerHTML shows records with status pending and for the month of October but **also shows 'No records found.'**

I get that the loop is checking all records hence showing both outputs.

**Question -**

How do I make sure it shows only shows only data as per selected options and not run the else condition.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) instead of fetching all documents from the collection and manually filtering out on client side. That'll save you many read as well. The [`querySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty) has a `empty` property that is `true` is no documents matched the query. Try:

```
// field names/values are case sensitive
const q = db.collection("col_name")
  .where("status", "==", "Pending")
  .where("month", "==", "October")

q.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
  removeOldRows()

  if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach(d => {
      let showData = `
                <tr class='tableDataRows'>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().name }</span></td>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().status }</span></td>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().type }</span></td>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().price }</span></td>
                    <td><span>${ doc.data().userEmail }</span></td>
                </tr>
            `
      tableRow.innerHTML += showData
    })
  } else {
    // No documents found
    // TODO: Show "No records found" message in UI
    alert("No records found")
  }
})
```